# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2501: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, unicode

I've been looking for solutions to this and haven't found any that worked. I've tried adding r in front of the filepath. I've tried changing the encoding to utf-8. Nothing seems to work.

I wrote this script on a Mac and it worked fine and I'm trying to run it on Windows but it's not working.

```
fin = open("C:\\Users\\filepath\\indivsWG22.txt", "rt", encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
fout = open("C:\\Users\\filepath\\Downloads\\out.csv", "w")
#for each line in the input file
for line in fin:
    #read replace the string and write to output file
    #This is where I deal with all the pipes and commas
    fout.write(line.replace(',', '^').replace('|~|',',').replace('|~',',').replace('~|',','))
#close input and output files
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

This is the full error I'm getting:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-22326598bb16> in <module>
      8 fout = open("C:\\Users\\filepath\\out.csv", "w")
      9 #for each line in the input file
---> 10 for line in fin:
     11         #read replace the string and write to output file
     12     #This is where I deal with all the pipes and commas

~\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input, final)
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     22     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 23         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
     24 
     25 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2501: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: This isn't a Windows issue. The error is right. ISO-8859-1 [doesn't have characters in the range 0x7F-0x9F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). That file wasn't created with ISO-8859-1

Comment: How was the file generated? Why not use UTF8 instead?

Comment: Is this the Euro sign? ISO-8859-1 doesn't include the Euro symbol. It was created in the 1990s, when the EU was still EEC. Try `cp1252` or `windows-1252` instead. Or use create the file using UTF8

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `€` (U+20AC,  *Euro Sign*) has code `0xE0` (128) in `cp1250` (`'€'.encode('cp1252')` -> `b'\x80'`). `0x81` isn't defined in `cp1252`!

Comment: @JosefZ you're right. So it's another codepage but definitely not ISO-8859-1. The OP will have to check how the file was created.